# Include language variable in url

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I have been developing a language plugin for wordpress which works completely. The only thing that is missing now is the url-rewriting. I have been looking at a lot of websites, sources and other questions on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get my permalinks to work.

I have been able to add a query string variable like so:

```
public function append_query_string($url) 
{
    $args = array('lang' => $this->get_locale());
    return add_query_arg($args, $url);
}
add_filter('page_link', array($this, 'append_query_string'));
add_filter('post_link', array($this, 'append_query_string'));
add_filter('the_permalink', array($this, 'append_query_string'));
```

This changes my links to `http://www.mylink.com?lang=en_us` for example. What I want now, is to add a permastruct so that user can have pretty url's (e.g. `http://www.mylink.com/en/`)

I have added the following piece of code:

```
public function add_query_var($vars)
{
    $vars['lang'] = $this->get_locale();
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('request' , array($this, 'add_query_var'), 10, 2 );

public function custom_permastruct() 
{
    add_permastruct('language', '%lang%', false);
}
add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'custom_permastruct'));
```

The only thing I need now is a rewrite rule, I presume, but I could be totally wrong. Anyone who knows what the best solution is for adding this permastruct?

Comment: Did you look into `add_query_arg`?
[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/]

Answer (score -1):

In your example

Change this:

```
public function custom_permastruct() 
{
    add_permastruct('language', '%lang%', false);
}
```

to this:

```
public function custom_permastruct() 
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%lang%','(lang)s','post_type=');
    add_permastruct('language', '%lang%', false);
}
```

**Please note that this will only work on WordPress 3.4+**

Other ways of doing it:

You need to create a new permalink and after to set some rewrite rules. The function add_permastruct is a good start.
You can find a good example here: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add and also here: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies--wp-25488

That's a media library example, but you can use the same functionality for your language module.

Comment: Please, add code and explanation to the answer itself. Use external links only as reference.

Comment: That's an entire tutorial, I didn't want to copy-paste it here since I had the option to just add a link to it. I'm not related to that website. It was a good example and that's why I recommended it.

Comment: Just add the relevant parts. If the link is dead, the answer is useless. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good point and a very strong argument.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Thanks for your feedback.